# Plotting region from list

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I have what should be a rather simple problem, but I am struggling with an elegant solution.

I have a nested list of values of the form `{{x1,y1,p1},{x2,y2,p2},...{xn,yn,pn}}` where `p` corresponds to the variable pair `x` and `y`.

Ultimately, I want to make `RegionPlot`s on the y-x plane of the points for which `p < some value`, i.e., I want to make a plot of the region where `p < 5`, then do the same for `p < 7`, etc. Ideally I would like to plot these regions on the same plot, with different colored dots depending on the p-value.

I am struggling with working with the nested list (despite having looked through the documentation), and having `RegionPlot` refer to particular list elements and compare with the third element of each nested set. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `ListPlot3D[xxx, RegionFunction-> Function[{z}, z<5]]`

Comment: I think you're looking for [`ListContourPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListContourPlot.html). It accepts data in exactly your format, and you can easily specify which contours to draw using [`Contours`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Contours.html) (i.e. which regions).

Comment: Have you seen `Select`?

Comment: `Select` will allow you to select the data that obeys some constraint, but if you use `RegionPlot` or simple `ListPlot3D`, etc., you will likely get the full range of positions, not restricted to where the data lie.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch - Thanks, have had a look at that. I guess in my case it would be something like ``Select[list, 5 < Last[#] < 7 &]``, although I am not sure how to pass this into a RegionPlot argument?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork - Thanks, I am definitely trying to use the functionality of RegionPlot or ListPlot directly. Your first suggestion with ListPlot3D doesn't really work as I am simply looking for a region on the (2D) ``x-y`` plane to be shaded in. While the shape of the 3D plot from ListPlot3D is encouraging, I am not sure if I need the extra dimension...any ideas how to select the last value in each subset and have a constraint on that in a RegionPlot argument? I am struggling with using RegionPlot on lists.

Comment: @LukasLang - That was very helpful, it does indeed do most of what I want and seems to be the best solution so far. The region boundaries are not always as smooth as I'd like, but I suppose I'll just need to scan across finer intervals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in  the comments, regions based on the third column can be plotted using `ListContourPlot`:

```
SeedRandom[1]
dt = RandomReal[10, {100, 3}];

pbins = {2, 5, 7};
colors = ColorData[97, "ColorList"];

lcp =ListContourPlot[dt, ImageSize -> 500, PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
 InterpolationOrder -> 0, Contours -> pbins, 
 ContourShading -> (Opacity[.5, #] & /@ colors) ]
```

[image]

Grouping data based on the third column can be done using a combination of `Nearest` and `GroupBy` or using `HistogramList` with a custom height function to bin data by the the third column.

#### Nearest + GroupBy

```
pbins = {2, 5, 7}; 
binlims = {Floor[Min[dt[[All, -1]]]] - $MachineEpsilon, ## & @@ pbins, 
       $MachineEpsilon + Ceiling[Max[dt[[All, -1]]]]} ;
nf = Nearest[binlims -> "Index"];
parentBin = If[binlims[[First@nf@#]] <= #, 
    binlims[[{#, # + 1} &@First@nf[#]]], 
    binlims[[{# - 1, #} &@First@nf[#]]] ] &;
bl1 = Values @ GroupBy[SortBy[dt, Last], parentBin[Last@#] & -> (#[[;; 2]] &)];
lp1 = ListPlot[bl1, PlotStyle -> PointSize[Large]];
Show[lcp, lp1]
```

[image]

#### HistogramList

```
binspecs = {1, 1, {binlims}};
heightfunc = BinLists[dt, {#[[1]]}, {#[[2]]}, {#[[3]]}] &;
bl2 = HistogramList[dt, binspecs, heightfunc][[2, 1, 1]][[All, All, ;; 2]]; 
Sort /@ bl2 == Sort/@ bl1
```

> True

```
lp2 = ListPlot[bl2, PlotStyle -> PointSize[Large]] ;
Show[lcp, lp2]
```

> same picture